# How to check programmatically string type in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

How do I check if a string is of type `std::string` or is of type `const char*`?

```
template<typename B>
B check(B b)
{
    //
}
```

`check` may be called with a `std::string` or a `const char*`
I'm not sure how to deduce the return type. How to determine if it should be `std::string` or `const char*`?

Comment: [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)?

Comment: If you only have to deal with `const char *` and `std::string` maybe using a template is overkill...

Answer (score 5):

As I wrote in a comment, if you only have to deal with `const char *` and `std::string` maybe using a template is overkill.

However, if you really want to do it, you can use `if constexpr`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename B>
B check(B b)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<B, std::string>) {
        std::cout << "std::string" << std::endl;
        return b;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<B, const char*>) {
        std::cout << "const char *" << std::endl;
        return b;
    } else {
        throw; // obviously you might want do to something different
    }
}

int main() {
    check("ciao");
    check(std::string{"ciao"});
    check(1); // throws
}
```

Also, you might want to guard *before* the `if constexpr` with a static assertion:

```cpp
template<typename B>
B check(B b)
{
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<const char *, B>); // just an idea
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<B, std::string>) {
        std::cout << "std::string" << std::endl;
        return b;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<B, const char*>) {
        std::cout << "const char *" << std::endl;
        return b;
    } else {
        std::cout << "other type convertible from `const char *`" << std::endl;
    }

}

int main() {
    check("ciao");
    check(std::string{"ciao"});
    //check(1); // fails at compile time
}
```